# What is the effect of emission of of Gamma/Delta brain waves during meditation?

Tags: meditation

In his Forward to the book **"Vedic Yoga: The Path of the Rishi", by Sri David Frawley**, Sri Mahamandaleshvara Dr. Swami Veda Bharati states as follows:

> In the lab of his Ashram's Meditation Research Institute in Rishikesh,
>   Swami Veda Bharati has demonstrated that in the depth of meditation he
>   produces 101 Hz of Gamma waves on one hand and on the other hand he
>   produces below 0.5 Hz delta brain waves; this apparently has never
>   been recorded before in the research of neurology on meditation.

My question is whether such emission during meditation that extra-ordinary?  If so, what will be the outcome of such emission?

Comment: Perhaps it reflects the state of consciousness. More subtle the waves, his consciousness is also expanded beyond physical state. This would more of be a scientifc answer type than answer from hindu perspective!

Comment: I prefer a simple answer which may contain a few scientific terms,  if necessary .@Akshay

Comment: This might be off topic (already 2 close votes as I write this). As scientific speculation is off topic here. There is no way of answering this from Yogic scriptures as they won't talk about such rays.. so people can only speculate @srimannarayanakv

Comment: You can close as per the rules of this site.   It is nothing to do about science or speculation.   I am just curious to know the effect of such emissions in simple terms only. @Rickross

Comment: Already closed, unfortunately many good Qs do not have any place here .. that's how the users have decided regarding the guidelines ..:) @srimannarayanakv

Comment: @Rickross: no problem.  I can understand.:-)